# Spring unit testing, how to check that methods store info in db?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and currently I am trying to perform unit testing for my project. I have configured spring with hibernate and now I want to check if methods of the created classes work. For instance, let's say I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class DefaultProduct implements Product, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
private String productName;

@Column(name = "product_price", nullable = false)
private double productPrice;

@Column(name = "product_quantity", nullable = false)
private int productQuantity;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
private Set<DefaultAccount> account;

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public double getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public int getProductQuantity() {
    return productQuantity;
}

public void setProductQuantity(int productQuantity) {
    this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
}

public Set<DefaultAccount> getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(Set<DefaultAccount> account) {
    this.account = account;
}
```

How to correctly test these methods? What is the best option? I am used to *assertTrue* and *assertFalse* in JUnit testing, but I am afraid this won't be a good option in my case.
Thank you.

Comment: do you want to test these pojo methods. well its also a java class right so why not test it with normal JUnit

Comment: What exactly do you want to test from the Entity?

Comment: I want to test whether these methods store information in the database or not, mate

Comment: You can setup an in-memory DB like H2 or any other. Set up your tests to connect to this DB, then test as you like. It does not make much sense to test simple CRUD functionality of your entities as you would be mainly testing the persistence framework (which hopefully has been tested extensively). You can test validations, cascading, relationships etc. Most of the CRUD functionality will probably be covered by tests for your business methods.

Comment: Plain model object does nothing for you. You need to implement DAO and service layers where would be the logic you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

A unit test should not be hitting the database. Unit testing a POJO should be at the lowest level of modularity.

Answer (score 1):

@Vaelyr is correct. You should be integration testing the DAO and service layer objects, i.e the ones that are actually putting the code into the DB.

You can test your DAO object with

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:context.xml"})
public class DaoIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
TheDaoObject theDaoObject;

@Test
public void testAdd() {
    theDaoObject.addSomething("one", "two");
}

@Test
public void testGet() {
    List<Something> somethingList = theDaoObject.getSomethingById("one");
    Assert.assertTrue("Something found", somethingList.size() > 0);
}
}
```